# What is the bug with the code given below?

Tags: python-2.7, machine-learning

I was reading programming collective intelligence and wrote the following code but am getting an error executing it.

```
from pydelicious import get_popular,get_userposts,get_urlposts
import time

def initializeUserDict(tag,count=5):
  user_dict={}
  # get the top count' popular posts
  for p1 in get_popular(tag=tag)[0:count]:
    # find all users who posted this
    for p2 in get_urlposts(p1['href']):
      user=p2['user']
      user_dict[user]={}
  return user_dict

def fillItems(user_dict):
  all_items={}
  # Find links posted by all users
  for user in user_dict:
    for i in range(3):
      try:
        posts=get_userposts(user)
        break
      except:
        print "Failed user '+user+', retrying"
        time.sleep(4)
      try:
        for post in posts:
            url=post['href']
            user_dict[user][url]=1.0
            all_items[url]=1
      except:
        print 'No Posts'

  # Fill in missing items with 0
  for ratings in user_dict.values():
    for item in all_items:
      if item not in ratings:
        ratings[item]=0.0
```

And am getting the following error:

```
In [33]: fillItems(delusers)
Failed user ,retrying
Failed user ,retrying
Failed user ,retrying
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
UnboundLocalError                         Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-33-ee215affceae> in <module>()
----> 1 fillItems(delusers)

C:\Users\Blue\Anaconda\deliciousrec.py in fillItems(user_dict)
     20         posts=get_userposts(user)
     21         break
---> 22       except:
     23         print "Failed user '+user+', retrying"
     24         time.sleep(4)

UnboundLocalError: local variable 'posts' referenced before assignment
```

Answer (score 0):

After 3 attempts in the for loop:

```
for i in range(3):
  try:
    posts=get_userposts(user)
    break
  except:
    print "Failed user '+user+', retrying"
    time.sleep(4)
```

(Since there is:

```
Failed user ,retrying
Failed user ,retrying
Failed user ,retrying
```

)
`posts` isn't defined (because the `get_userposts` failed). Thus local variable `posts` is referenced in `for post in posts` but was not assigned yet.

Comment: Yeah,I know that but I don't know how to resolve the issue of Failed user ,retrying.May be the delicious api is not responding.

Comment: @DiscoDancer then I don't understand what is your problem: Why dit it fail for the user? (Because we can't guess from your post) or how to deal with `posts` being empty?

Comment: the function of the api pydelicious,get_usersposts gets post from user name passed as an argument